# How can I generate bookmark able URLs while loading jquery content dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In my header I have the following script to receive an id parameter input to the function recp() :

```
<script>
 function take(id) {
  $('#content_div').load('pages.php?id='+id);
 }
</script>
```

In my navigation menu in the body, I have my links set as follows:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="take('food')">Food</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="take('animals')">Animals</a></li>
```

My div tag is like this in the body:

```
<div id="content_div"><div>
```

pages.php has a conditional structure to inject specific code into the #content_div as follows:

```
 <?php
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 function showUp($id){
 switch($id){
 case "food":
 include_once "food.php";
 break;
 case "animals":
 include_once'animals.php';
 break;
 }
 ?>
```

The content is loading perfectly but I have issues with the URL. How can I achieve to use the back button and navigate to the previously opened state such that they can be bookmarked?

Comment: Isn't `$().load()` in jQuery an event (onLoad) that you bind a function to?

Comment: Simple answer is, you can't. When loading content dynamically you either have to use hashes or HTML5's History API to change the URL without loading a new page.

Comment: Can you post the minimal implementation of the hash or HTML5? That's exactly what I need to figure. I have sweat over it for quite a while

Comment: I am not clarify with your question..what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Let's say I click the food link then my div loads food.php contents, and then I click animals to load animals.php. After loading animals.php, I should be able to go back to the div loading food.php by the means of the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to push browser history state programmatically in your case. History.js – handling this issue. Here you can take code and manual: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js